# Tiny Death Star Mission- Build One More Of Any Level(s)

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

One of the missions on Tiny Death Star is build one more of any level. I built another food level, but nothing happened. I also checked to see if I could buy the same level twice, but I couldn't. Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Did your level complete construction?  If not, you will not get credit from the Emperor.  Once the level is completed, the picture of the Emperor will have force lightning surrounding it and you will get credit.

Comment: I also think if you started the level before he gave you the task it won't count it.  You have to build the level, and wait for it to complete, after he gives you the task.

Comment: I'm not certain that matters.  I'm about 95% certain I've lucked into a few mission completions with levels that were already under construction.